# What is the default file to be visited behind a website?

Tags: http, curl

When I open a website's url such as www.stackoverflow.com via curl, which file is actually being visited in the server? I know usually it is index.html. But I cannot find such a convention in the RFC2616 document. How can I know it?

BR

Answer (score 1):

The document dilivered by calling a website without a path in the URL is configured by the webserver. So you have no standard there. Is a users joice.

Curl will download the file the webserver is delivering him, or follow the redirect (if -L option is given) when webserver responses a redirect.

Comment: `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is `false` by default as far as I know so there will not be a redirect by default

Comment: @DarkBee you are right curl -L <URL> will follow redirect

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for the client to know how the data for the HTTP response was generated. It might not even be related to a specific file.

The last time I wrote a significant bit of server side code, everything outside of `/static/` was routed (via mod_rewrite) though a FastCGI program that got its data from a few different controller libraries, a dozen database schema libraries, a database and a dozen template files.

The WWW is built on links between URLs, not files. Don't worry about files if you are writing client code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily `index.html`, and you can't actually know that it could be anything depending on the Server Configuration, for instance in [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) you can change the directory index to the one that suits you

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

in this case the default file accessed is `home.php`

in [IIS](http://www.iis.net/) you can take a [look](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument) about default index and how to change it

but the defaults are

in [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/)

```
index.php (usually: depending on the server configuration)
index.html (is the default that comes with a fresh install)
```

in [IIS](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument)

```
Default.htm
Default.asp
Index.htm
Index.html
Iisstart.htm
```